# How do I randomly return an element from an array in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, irb

I will like to select a name randomly from an  array list then display either in Capital or Lowercase

For example names= ["James", "John", "Jane"]
Output should be:  JOHN or john or jane or JAMES or JANE or james

Please help!

I have tried using the .sample() command which selects from an array. Also, I'm aware of the .upcase() and .lowercase(), the problem now is how to combine these whole methods together in order to get the desire result which is to select a name randomly for the array list then display in either Capital or Lowercase.

```
 def random_case(*names)
  names= ["James", "John", "Jane"]
  names.sample { |names| names.upcase  names.downcase }
  puts "Hello #{names}! How are you today?"
 end
```

random_case()

I expect the output to be JOHN or john or jane or JAMES or JANE or james - randomly

Comment: Your first two sentences are contradictory. How can you select one name and return an object (is that a string?) that references all names?  You say, "...then display either in Capital or Lowercase". Well, which is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 def random_case(names)  
   names.flat_map{|name| [name.upcase, name.downcase, name.capitalize]}.sample
 end

 names= ["James", "John", "Jane"]

 puts random_case names
```

I think the code is quite simple to understand. Any trouble? leave a comment to let me know

Comment: Thank you for your help. Please see further question and your help is highly need -` https://stackoverflow.com/q/56864526/6651760

Comment: Hi @ChristopherEzimoha it's good to know it helps. Could you mark this as  solution first, and then, reformat your code in your new question, so other can see it better

Comment: Please don't ask the OP to select your answer, it's unbecoming. Had the OP been an SO veteran they would have merely disregarded the request; this OP, clearly new to SO, may not realise that there is no rush to select an answer, that most members wait at least a couple of hours before doing so. Christopher, invoking each method on the each name, then selecting one array randomly, is generally poor practice, better to select one name randomly then invoke each method on that name.

Answer (score 2):

I would start with:

```
def random_case(*names)
  name = names.sample                                # pick a random name
  [true, false].sample ? name.upcase : name.downcase # return name with random format
end

random_case("James", "John", "Jane")    
#=> "JAMES"
random_case("James", "John", "Jane")
#=> "john"
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd write *two* methods. One for returning a random name out of a list of names:

```
def random_name(*names)
  names.sample
end
```

and another one for changing a given name's case: (`rand < 0.5` has a 50% chance of being `true`)

```
def random_case(name)
  if rand < 0.5
    name.upcase
  else
    name.downcase
  end
end
```

Then combine both:

```
5.times do
  puts random_case(random_name("James", "John", "Jane"))
end
```

Output:

```
JOHN
JOHN
jane
JAMES
james
```

---

If you don't like the `rand < 0.5` approach, you could also put both variants into an array and pick one randomly:

```
def random_case(name)
  [name.upcase, name.downcase].sample
end
```

Or you could put the method names `:upcase` and `:downcase` in an array, pick one of them randomly and use [`public_send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Object.html#method-i-public_send) to invoke that method:

```
def random_case(name)
  name.public_send([:upcase, :downcase].sample)
end
```

Comment: #3, #2,  because in most contexts that's generally not a good idea, and the OP may be impressionable.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this.

```
 names= ["James", "John", "Jane"]
 random = [names.sample.upcase, names.sample.downcase].sample
 puts "Hello #{random}! How are you today?"
```